# How to run a Spring Boot microservice multiple instances or times at the same time?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I have one Spring Boot Microservice that will generate data like half an hour for one user. I need to run the same microservice at the same time to generate data for multiple users. So how to create or run the same microservice multiple times or instances?

Answer (score 0):

Am not 100% sure that this is the best way , but you can use gradle bootrun with multiple ports to run the same instance like this

`./gradlew bootRun --args='--server.port=8888'`

and if you are using maven , you can do it like this

`mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--server.port=8085`

and there are [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) that can be used and set when running like this

`./gradlew bootRun --args='--spring.profiles.active=dev'`

so you will need to create few profile and then run each one alone .

am pretty sure that there is a smarter way though .